# do httpwebrequest but without waiting for response

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, webrequest, httpwebresponse

Here i do not want to wait for response from server because i do not care about response for
these httpwebrequest.

is it ok? or will it affect system in future?

```
HttpWebRequest PostRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(PostUrl);
        PostRequest.ContentType = PostContentType;
        PostRequest.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DataUrl);            
        try
        {
            PostRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            using (Stream webpageStream = PostRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                webpageStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call asynchronous `BeginGetRequestStream()` and then handle response data when it completes. If you don't need response data, then you can just ignore it, but you might be interested in obtaining a response status code to check if your request succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

yeah just dont forget to add these lines

```
  webpageStream.Flush();
  webpageStream.Close();
```

Comment: Close is not needed as the using will handle that part.

Answer (score 0):

yest the befor this answer is so true , remove this codes:

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var responseString = new SreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

and add the flowing code on using stream like this after stream.write:

```
stream.Flush();
stream.Close();
```